# Laravel show me 404 error in domain catalog

Tags: laravel, .htaccess

I have shared hosting without ssh access. I transfer my Laravel project from localhost to domain catalog:

```
www.test.domain.com/laravel
```

My .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /laravel

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

In my .env file I set like this:

```
APP_URL=/laravel
```

And i get 404 Not Found error page. In plesk i see this error

`2019-09-08 05:20:44  Error   xx.xxx.xxx.xxx  404 GET /laravel/ HTTP/1.1`

Any advice?

Comment: As shown in [the config file](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/config/app.php#L55) and [the default .env file](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/.env.example#L5), `APP_URL` should be a **URL**, not a path. Also AFAIK there are other steps needed to install Laravel in shared hosting, where your docroot is not `/public` - there are many guides for this.

Comment: I think this is not a problem. I set it as you write, but it still doesn't work. Laravel works and he shows me a 404 error - so the problem is probably in the route settings.